# Cursor in a trigger not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following cursor code in a trigger to move 5 records every hour into a new table cursor works fine independently but when in trigger it isn't working.
TableA gets truncated before every load.

my cursor logic

```
  Declare @a[varchar](50),@b[varchar](50),@c[varchar](50),@d[varchar](50),@e[varchar](50)
-- declare a cursor
DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [a]
      ,[b]
      ,[c]
      ,[d]
      ,[e]
       FROM TableA

-- open cursor and fetch first row into variables
OPEN insert_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into  @a,@b,@c,@d,@e

-- check for a new row
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
-- do complex operation here
Insert into TableB
SELECT  @a,@b,@c,@d,@e
-- get next available row into variables
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into  @a,@b,@c,@d,@e
END
close insert_cursor
Deallocate insert_cursor
```

My cursor in trigger code:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER IO_ABC_INSERT  ON TABLEA 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @a[varchar](50),@b[varchar](50),@c[varchar](50),@d[varchar](50),@e[varchar](50)
-- declare a cursor
DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [a]
      ,[b]
      ,[c]
      ,[d]
      ,[e]
       FROM TableA

-- open cursor and fetch first row into variables
OPEN insert_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into  @a,@b,@c,@d,@e

-- check for a new row
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
-- do complex operation here
Insert into TableB
SELECT  @a,@b,@c,@d,@e
-- get next available row into variables
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into  @a,@b,@c,@d,@e
END
close insert_cursor
Deallocate insert_cursor
END
```

Can any one point me where exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: A Cursor is usually a bad idea, inside a trigger it's event worst. Also, your trigger is an instead of insert trigger which means that no rows are inserted into the table unless you insert them inside the trigger itself.

Comment: I understand but just for 5 rows every hour so thought this process would be good any pointers for any other way is highly appreciated.

Comment: First, this kind of task fits a scheduled job better then a trigger. Second, You need to figure out what five records you want to copy first. Your current code just takes all the records from tableA and inserts them one by one to tableB.

Comment: TableA gets truncated before every load

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting from TableA inserted table,which means you are inserting all the table values of TableA for every insert on TableA into TableB

You could change your trigger to setbased..Instead of insert on your code means..

*When insert happens on TableA insert in TableB...There will be no inserts in tableA.*.

Change your code to below for set based..

```
 CREATE TRIGGER IO_ABC_INSERT  ON TABLEA 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

Insert into TableB
select a,b,c,d,e from Inserted

End
```

Comment: what are you expecting,..What do you mean by not working ..?do you want insert values of TableA into TableB 5 random values every hour when insert happens on A

Comment: Yes @TheGameiswar what I meant as not working is when ever I insert new values in TableA they are not getting inserted into TableB

Comment: that's what code does,but whenever the insert happens on tableA.

Comment: I tried implementing using FOR INSERT/AFTER INSERT rather than INSTEAD OF INSERT and also used inserted table, I am still unable to load the new data from tableA to tableB